# Why strcpy crashes?

Tags: c, strcpy

Why does the call to strcpy crashes in the following code? Also why is it crashing in CodeBlocks, but not in VS?

```
#define MAX 500
char* GetUserAnswer(char* detail)
{
    char answer[MAX];
    printf("Provide %s:", detail);
    scanf("%s", answer);

    return answer;
}

void PrelucreazaSablon(FILE* generatedFile)
{
    char answer[MAX];
    strcpy(answer, GetUserAnswer("name"));
    fputs(answer, generatedFile);
}
```

Comment: You have undefined behavior because the returned pointer from `GetUserAnswer` is out of scope when you try to access it.

Comment: You return a dangling pointer, since the local array `answer` is already destroyed when it arrives to `strcpy`. This causes "undefined behavior", which may manifest as a crash, but doesn't have to.